# No Module Named Socket

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, secure-crt

Im trying to use the socket module in a logon script for SecureCRT. When run from my command line, the script runs perfectly but once I try to run it through SecureCRT it tells me there is no socket module.
Im using python 3.7 and have made sure socket is in my lib. My lib is also mapped for path.

Here is the script Im running:

```
import socket
import datetime
timeIn=(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d %B %Y %H:%M:%S'))
hostname = socket.gethostname()
hostip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
t=open("secCRT.txt", "w")
t.write('testing script \n')
t.write(timeIn)
t.write(' host: '+  hostname)
t.write(' ip: '+ hostip)
t.close()
```

When run from my command line it works perfectly but when run inside crt, it states there is no module named socket (no module named _socket).
Ive seen there are similar posts to this but none that have been able to help me yet.

**EDIT #1**

Here is the way python is mapped to the path system variable:

[image]

**EDIT #2**

Tried moving _socket.py and socket.py for version 3.7 to the same directory as the script but still getting errors. **edit*** also socket.cpython-37.pyc

**EDIT #3**

Im wondering, because this is a logon script (run when a connection is made to a server), could it be looking for the socket module on the server im connected to instead of the local machine? The script itself is on the local machine.

**EDIT #4** : from command line not logon script

```
>>> import sys
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(sys.path)
['',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python\\Python37\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python\\Python37',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']
```

**EDIT #5**

I was able to do this as a script within the SecureCRT application

```
with open("secCRT.txt", "w") as sout:
    sout.write(pprint.pformat(vars(pprint)))
```

Several of the lines reference this file:

```
C:\Program Files\VanDyke Software\Clients\vpython27.zip
```

This leads me to believe they are using verison 2.7. When I searched inside `vpython27.zip` for "socket" the `socket.pyc` and `SocketServer.pyc` were the only items that came up.
Does this mean I would want to find a `socket.py` or any other dependencies for version 2.7 and move them there?

**EDIT #6** : explanation from developer (VanDyke)

```
"  - The _socket module is built out by default as a .pyd
    file on Windows. This is effectively a .dll that can be
    loaded by the Python interpreter. Unfortunately, .pyd's
    can *not* be loaded out of the Python distribution zip
    file we ship."
```

**EDIT #7** : here is how VanDyke suggested I get the data I was looking for

```
objTab=crt.GetScriptTab()
objConfig=objTab.Session.Config
strHostname=objConfig.GetOption('Hostname')
strSessName=objTab.Session.Path
```

This solution works great for my environment.

Comment: Could you explicit "_run when a connection is made to a server_"? Also, are you using `venv`?

Comment: @Arount Im not using venv. The application (SecureCRT) has an option to place a python script to be run when a connection is made to a server through the application.

Comment: Ok, so you need to install dependencies on the server

Comment: @Arount seems like that could be the case but not always possible. Contacting the company for clarification.

Comment: Could you print paths from which python takes modules with: `import sys;import pprint; pprint.pprint(sys.path)`?

Comment: @AlexBaranowski see edit #4

Comment: @Newb4YouBB are paths the same in both cases (local console and running it with SecureCRT)?

Comment: @AlexBaranowski it was a rather large output but the only directories mentioned all seem to be a sub-directory of `C:\Program Files\VanDyke Software\Clients\vpython27.zip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WORKING SOLUTION**

VanDyke suggested I use the following code to get the Hostname and Session name with python used as a logon script.

```
objTab=crt.GetScriptTab()
objConfig=objTab.Session.Config
strHostname=objConfig.GetOption('Hostname')
strSessName=objTab.Session.Path
```